# Handling exception in Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, exception

I have a Servlet.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
       try
       {
        CallSomeMethodInBean();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
       //What to do here?
       }
    }
}
```

And in my Bean, I have `CallSomeMethodInBean()` method

```
public String CallSomeMethodInBean() throws Exception
{
 try
  {
    //Try something
  }
  catch(Throwable e)
  {
    throw new Exception(e);
  } 
}
```

And in my `web.xml`, I have configured error page if `java.lang.Exception` is thrown.

```
<error-page>
   <exception-type>javax.lang.Exception</exception-type>
   <location>/WEB-INF/pages/errorPage.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

Since `doPost()` method is calling `CallSomeMethodInBean()` method which throws Exception, I 
 need to surround `CallSomeMethodInBean` method with `try catch` block and need to catch
 the Exception.

Whatever exception was thrown in `CallSomeMethodInBean` in bean was handled through 
 `web.xml` configuration. So, what should I handle in `doPost()` method? Just pring a log message?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would reconsider your bean. Catching a Throwable means "I can handle any problems", but your exception handling code just wraps the Throwable into checked Exception. That is every other component which wants to use your bean have to wrap it try-catch code. If you cannot handle the checked exceptions from your bean, consider wrapping them into runtime exceptions and rethrow them.

Exceptions should be use only for exceptional situations. Catching Throwable and declaring "throws Exception" is considered as a bad practice. Declare only those exceptions, which can be handled meaningfully. Catch only those exceptions, which you know how to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need some specific error handling (like fixing object state etc) in this case and error page shown is enough for you, just rethrow it, or catch and ignore.